# Не могу запустить консольное приложение .bat через pywinauto

Tags: python, bat, pywinauto

Мне необходимо запустить программу и ввести в неё данные, пример программы: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При попытки запустить её при помощи pywinauto код ниже:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application(backend="uia").start(r'G:\Documents\Python\auto_old_dump\dump\start.bat')
```

Python выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Documents\Python\auto_old_dump\auto_old_dump_2.py", line 9, in <module>
    app = Application(backend="uia").start(r'G:\Documents\Python\auto_old_dump\dump\start.bat')
  File "C:\Users\barsi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 1075, in start
    if wait_for_idle and not app_idle():
  File "C:\Users\barsi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 1061, in app_idle
    result = win32event.WaitForInputIdle(
pywintypes.error: (1471, 'WaitForInputIdle', 'Не удалось завершить запрошенную операцию, так как указанный процесс не является процессом графического интерфейса пользователя.')

G:\Documents\Python\auto_old_dump>dotnet Dumper.dll
```

Что уже только не делал разобраться так и не смог...

Comment: Там ожидается ввод насколько я вижу...и в скрипте я его не наблюдаю.

Comment: Ввод сейчас неважен. Мне для начала в принципе бы запустить программу что на скриншоте.

Comment: А зачем для _консольного_ приложения `pywinauto`? Оно же стандартным `subprocess.run` запускается обычно.

Comment: Ну а вообще-то приложения `start.bat` не существует, надо запускать `cmd.exe` с нужными параметрами, т.е. "батиком".

Comment: Спасибо, буду изучать subprocess

Answer (score 1):

Через cmd.exe должен и pywinauto запускать:

```
app = Application(backend="uia").start(
    r'cmd.exe /c G:\Documents\Python\auto_old_dump\dump\start.bat',
    create_new_console=True,
    wait_for_idle=False
)
```

Опция `/k` создаёт новую консоль, опция `/c` выполняет команду и выходит. Вообще, конечно, странно скрипты запускать через pywinauto. Интерактивно что-то вводить в консоль - это не работа для инструмента автоматизации GUI. Можно просто подать на stdin какой-то текст. Например:

```
start.bat <"Stdin text"
```

Просто под ввод текста именно в консоль pywinauto вообще не заточена. Технически есть возможность реализовать это (есть фича реквест где-то на гитхабе), но зачем? Если можно проще.

Ну и да, `subprocess.check_output("start.bat", shell=True)` или что-то типа того вполне уместно.